# html2canvas stops after rendering finishes

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, html2canvas

I am trying to get a link of image generated by `html2canvas` like this:

**App.js:**

```
function capture() { 
  console.log('capture running')
  html2canvas(document.getElementById('leaderboard-div'), {
    letterRendering: 1, allowTaint: true, onrendered: function (canvas) {
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
      console.log(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"))   
    }
  }) 
}
```

**Leaderboard.html -**

```
<body> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/html2canvas/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
  <script src="./app.js"></script>       

  <div id="leaderboard-div" style="height: 450px; width: 750px; background-color: #202124; border-radius: 24px;">
    <div id="rank-1" style="background-color: #2d2e31; height: 140px; width: 100%;">
      <img id="rank-1-pic" class="top-rank-image" 
        src="someURL">
      <p id="rank-1-name" style="color: #ffffff; font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;">Name</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="btnCap" onclick="capture()">Test</button>

</body>
```

Here is what the console shows:

[image]

Nothing in the `function(canvas)` works.

I need to get that link in the console or in a variable so I can export the image somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

I reckon I have found a solution to your problem.
Looking at the code, it seems like you have followed an outdated tutorial which uses the old api. The `onrendered` does not work anymore. Nowadays the `html2canvas` uses a promise. Which basically means that you have to add a `.then` after `html2canvas(document.getElementById('leaderboard-div'), { letterRendering: 1, allowTaint: true,})`. Like so:

```js
function capture() {
  console.log('capture running')
  html2canvas(document.getElementById('leaderboard-div'), {
    letterRendering: 1,
    allowTaint: true,
  }).then(canvas => {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    console.log(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"))
  });
}
```

Be careful however with cross origin images. That might give you an error like:

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: SecurityError: The operation is insecure.

Or

> file.html: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.

For more info on that see the [github repo](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues?q=Uncaught+%28in+promise%29+DOMException%3A+Failed+to+execute+%27toDataURL%27+on+%27HTMLCanvasElement%27%3A+Tainted+canvases+may+not+be+exported.+)

Hope this helps! If not, please comment